# How to convert one element of Object into array of instances?

Tags: java, android, arrays, class, instance

I have this this class `People` with fields name, phone, email, and address. There are many instances of this class. How can I get an array of all of the instances of the name element. For example, 
`String[] array = "John, Tim, Harry"`. So, all I want to do is take one element out of every instance and create an array of them. I have been working on this for a long time. Help is greatly appreciated. By the way, all of the fields are strings.

Comment: What about this `String[] array = {"John", "Tim", "Harry"}`?

Comment: @Braj That is an example of what I want my array to look like, an array of strings that are names.

Comment: Is there some reason you need a separate array of just the names?  Why not just keep an array of `People` and call `getName()` on each one when you need the name?

Comment: 1. I am going to use the array for an arrayadapter to populate a listview.

Comment: 2. How do I reference a specific instance of the object so I can loop through to make an arraylist?

Comment: You have to have a variable pointing to each `People` you want to access.  How are you currently storing all of your `People` objects?

Comment: I just have them of instances of my class. I used my constructor to make them. Is there something else I need to do to save them because when I did `People.name`, it returned null

Comment: `People.name`???  You didn't make `name` a static field, did you?

Comment: But when you construct an object, normally you assign it to a variable, like `People p = new People("foo", "bar", "baz");`.  You can then use the variable p to reference the object you've created.  If you have bunches of them, you usually put them in a `List<People>`, so that you can later loop through all of the `People` you've got.

Comment: I think you need to edit your post to add the `People` class and the code where you are using it.  You seem to have some misconceptions about the way Java handles objects.

Comment: After the user selects a name from your list view, do you want to be able to find the `People` object that has this name?  If so, that will be difficult if all you have is an array of strings--how do you plan to go back from the name `String` to the `People` object?  An alternative is to write a custom `ArrayAdapter` that can take a list of `People`, not necessarily a list of `String`s, but it's a little tricky.  See https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/.

Comment: Actually, Khaled's second example seems to demonstrate the same thing as the above link.

Comment: Ok. I never thought about how I would be able to reference them. I guess I was just a little rusty. I will try the custom adapter as in Kahled Leli's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1-Create People model**

```
public class People {
private String name;
private String phone;
private String address;
public People(String name, String phone, String address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.address = address;
}
/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
/**
 * @return the phone
 */
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
/**
 * @param phone the phone to set
 */
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
/**
 * @return the address
 */
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
/**
 * @param address the address to set
 */
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

}
```

**2-Create your custom adapter**

```
public class PeopleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<People> peopleItems;

public PeopleListAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<People> peopleItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.peopleItems = peopleItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return peopleItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return peopleItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.people_list_item, null);
    }
    // TODO
    /**
     * Return some list row..
     */
    TextView nameTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView phoneTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    TextView addressTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);

    nameTxt.setText(peopleItems.get(position).getName());
    phoneTxt.setText(peopleItems.get(position).getPhone());
    phoneTxt.setText(peopleItems.get(position).getAddress());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

**Update**

```
private ArrayList<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();
peopleList.add(new People("name1", "phone1","address1");
peopleList.add(new People("name2", "phone2","address2");

// adaptor
PeopleListAdapter adaptor = new PeopleListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),peopleList);
//some list view
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hoping this code to help you to list people as rows on listview, But if you want to extract name from `People` model in form of `String names[]`,you can use @user2545722 or @Sean N. answers.

Comment: It helped a lot. One more thing. Where do I put it? because if I put it in onCreate, the listview isn't made yet, but if I put it in onViewCreated, it never gets called. I am using fragments.

Comment: @user2297366 `onCreateView` to set layout that contain listview `  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container,false);`. then init listview and add the code above at `onActivityCreated`, `Listview listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);`

Comment: I don't have the same parameters in my `onCreateView`. I don't have any `ViewInflator` or `ViewGroup`. I may have gotten around the inflator. This is my line of code so far:

Comment: `View v = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.activity_speaker_list,???? );`.It wants a `ViewGroup` for the second argument, but I have no idea what to use. The only parameters for the method are `View view` and `Bundle savedInstanceState`. If I am reading your logic correctly. You want me to inflate the fragment in `onCreateView` and put the adapter in `onActivityCreated`? There is no `onActivityCreated` in `ListFragment` and the `listView` is built into the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but I'll show 2 ways:

If you have your instances of Person declares as single variables, it'll look like this:

```
Person p1 = new Person("name1");
Person p2 = new Person("name2");
Person p3 = new Person("name3");
```

(I ignored the other Person's fields to make this easier.)

Now you can put those Persons in an Person[] (Person Array)

```
Person[] persons = new Person []{p1, p2, p3};
```

Now we will loop trough the persons (I suppouse you have the .getName() method in you Person class)

```
String[] names = new String[persons.length]; // Create names Array
for (int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++)     //Loop the persons Array
{
    names[i] = persons[i].getName();         //Take the name from persons in
                                             //position [i] and put it in position
                                             //[i] of the names Array.
}
```

The other way is directly placing the names:

```
String[] names = new String[]{p1.getName(), p2.getName(), p3.getName()};
```

Comment: Great Answer. It answers the exact question that I had, but I forgot about referencing the objects once the item has been clicked. So +1 for answering my question, but not accepted because another guy had the foresight to tell me why my question was the wrong one to ask.

Comment: Yes, that is the right way for your problem. But I can't imagine how somebody is doing something so advanced without knowing something so basic. I have been programming Java for 2 years and I never came across the View Object.

Comment: This is for android. You see many different types of `View` objects that you need to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through each instance of the People class and store each name in an ArrayList.  Then convert the ArrayList to a String using toArray().  Something kind of like this:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (People p1 : myList) names.add(p1.getName());
String allnames[] = names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
```